# Obtener valor de una propiedad en un bucle for ... in

Tags: javascript, bucles

Ahora mismo tengo este objeto:

```
{
    day: '10-08-21',
    init: '14:26:14',
    binit: '14:26:15',
    bend: '14:26:16',
    end: '14:26:16'
}
```

Dicho objeto lo estoy iterando en un bucle, pero solo obtengo el nombre de la la propiedad (`day`, `init`, `binit`, etc).

Me gustaría poder sacar el valor de dicha propiedad.

Aquí muestro cómo tengo el bucle:

```
function viewData(data){

    console.log(data);

    let num = data.length;
    
    for(let i = 0; i < num; i++){
        let tr = document.createElement('tr');

        for(n in data[i]){
            let th = document.createElement('th');

            console.log(n);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu código bastaba con usar `data[i][n]` para obtener el dato que necesitabas:

```
for (n in data[i]) {
    console.log(data[i][n]);
}
```

Pero te recomiendo que iteres por cada elemento haciendo uso de `forEach`:

```
data.forEach(elemento => {
    /* En elemento aparecerán uno a uno los elementos de la matriz */
});
```

Si quisieras conocer el índice del elemento al que estamos accediendo, podrías obtenerlo usando el segundo parámetro (opcional) de la siguiente manera:

```
data.forEach((elemento, i) => {
    /* "elemento" vale "data[i]", donde "i" es el índice actual */
});
```

Posteriormente puedes iterar por cada propiedad de la clase mediante un bucle [`for ... in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in):

```
for (const n in elemento){
    /* En "n" está el nombre de la propiedad */
    /* En "elemento[n]" su valor */
}
```

El código quedaría así:

```js
const data = [
  {
    day: '10-08-21',
    init: '14:26:14',
    binit: '14:26:15',
    bend: '14:26:16',
    end: '14:26:16'
  },
  {
    day: '01-01-01',
    init: '01:01:01',
    binit: '01:01:02',
    bend: '01:01:03',
    end: '01:01:04'
  },
];

function viewData(data) {
    console.log(data);
    let num = data.length;
    
    data.forEach(elemento => {
        const tr = document.createElement('tr');
        for (const n in elemento) {
            const th = document.createElement('th');
            console.log(n, elemento[n]);
        }
    });
}

viewData(data);
```

Comment: LoL, olvide por completo el forEach JAJAJAJAJAJAJAJ es cierto, gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que tienes un array con de objetos de este tipo, para recorrer el array de objetos puedes hacer:

```js
let data = [
{
    day: '10-08-21',
    init: '14:26:14',
    binit: '14:26:15',
    bend: '14:26:16',
    end: '14:26:16'
},
{
    day: '10-08-21',
    init: '14:26:14',
    binit: '14:26:15',
    bend: '14:26:16',
    end: '14:26:16'
}

];

for (let i=0;i<data.length;i++)
{
    console.log("day -> ", data[i].day);
    console.log("init -> ", data[i].init);
    console.log("binit -> ", data[i].binit);
    console.log("bend -> ", data[i].bend);
    console.log("end -> ", data[i].end);
}
```

Sí solo tienes el objeto, puedes acceder con variable.propiedad,

```js
let data =
{
    day: '10-08-21',
    init: '14:26:14',
    binit: '14:26:15',
    bend: '14:26:16',
    end: '14:26:16'
}


console.log("day -> ", data.day);
console.log("init -> ", data.init);
console.log("binit -> ", data.binit);
console.log("bend -> ", data.bend);
console.log("end -> ", data.end);
```